# Lower and upper bounds involving a logarithmic expression

Tags: inequality, logarithms, maxima-minima, upper-lower-bounds

I would like to know what are the upper and lower bounds of the given expression for $\theta\in(0,1)$
\begin{align*}
\rho(\theta) = \frac{6}{\theta^{2}}\left[-5\theta + (1+3\theta)\ln(1-\theta) + (3+\theta)\sqrt{\theta}\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{\theta}}{1-\sqrt{\theta}}\right)\right] - 3
\end{align*}

Perhaps one could propose to study its monotonicity, but the resulting expression $\rho'(\theta)$ is not much inviting to deal with. Any suggestions?

Comment: Plot it in https://www.wolframalpha.com/, it seems increasing on $(0, 1)$. Do you want to prove that its infimum is $\rho(0+)$ and its supremum is $\rho(1-)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Use the first few terms of the Taylor expansion of $\ln (1+x)$ as $$\ln (1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{n+1}\over n}x^n \quad,\quad -1<x<1$$

Comment: Could you please explain further?

Comment: For example by expanding the terms we obtain$$x\ge\ln(1+x)\ge x-{x^2\over 2}$$which can e.g. imply$$\ln(1+\sqrt \theta)\ge \sqrt{\theta}-{\theta\over 2}$$